# Show touch keyboard code works fine on computer but not on tablet?

Tags: c#, wpf, tablet

I have this code to show the keyboard and it works well on the computer but does not work on the tablet
Can you please help me.

```
try
{
    Process[] oskProcessArray = Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip");
    foreach (Process onscreenProcess in oskProcessArray)
    {
        onscreenProcess.Kill();
    }

    string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
    string keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
    Process.Start(keyboardPath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    PV.ShowError(ex);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the tablet has the executable in exactly the same place as the desktop? Are there any error messages?

Comment: iam not sure . and there is no any error messages

Comment: Make sure. Use File.Exists(keyboardPath) to check.